# What are some alternatives to SettingsPane in Windows 10 UWP apps?

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, uwp, windows-10

I am porting an 8.1 metro app to Windows 10 UWP but SettingsPane is deprecated.

I know Microsoft provides guidelines online but no actual implementation advice.

I am wondering if you guys have some idea on a path forward.

I provided key chunks of code to show what I am trying to fix.

I've browsed through some other questions here and the replies all link to the guidelines posted by Microsoft.

Unfortunately this document just provides general design guidelines but no actual implementation advice.

```
    protected override void OnWindowCreated(WindowCreatedEventArgs args)
    {
        base.OnWindowCreated(args);
        SettingsPane.GetForCurrentView().CommandsRequested += OnCommandsRequested;
    }

    private void OnCommandsRequested(SettingsPane sender, SettingsPaneCommandsRequestedEventArgs args)
    {
        AddCommand(args, "Location", ShowConnectionSettingsFlyout);
        AddCommand(args, "UI Options", ShowUISettingsFlyout);
    }

    private void AddCommand(SettingsPaneCommandsRequestedEventArgs args, string label, UICommandInvokedHandler handler)
    {
        args.Request.ApplicationCommands.Add(new SettingsCommand(label, label, handler));
    }
```

#### Errors

1.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS1069  The type name 'SettingsPane' could not be found in the
>   namespace 'Windows.UI.ApplicationSettings'.  This type has been
>   forwarded to assembly 'Windows, Version=255.255.255.255,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime'
>   Consider adding a reference to that assembly. 
>   CycleCount    C:\Users\xxxx\source\repos\CycleCount\CycleCount\App.xaml.cs    245 Active

2.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS0731  The type forwarder for type
>   'Windows.UI.ApplicationSettings.SettingsPaneCommandsRequestedEventArgs'
>   in assembly 'Windows' causes a
>   cycle CycleCount  C:\Users\xxxx\source\repos\CycleCount\CycleCount\App.xaml.cs    245 Active

3.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS0103  The name 'SettingsPane' does not exist in the current
>   context   CycleCount  C:\Users\xxxx\source\repos\CycleCount\CycleCount\App.xaml.cs    242 Active

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most common approach is to create a separate Settings page where you can essentially put the same XAML code as you had in the settings pane previously. Then you will need some place in your UI to put the settings button, usually this is in the `NavigationView` control, which even has a special area for settings, which can be shown by setting the [`NavigationView.IsSettingsVisible` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.navigationview.IsSettingsVisible) to `true`. You can handle the click event on this button and navigate to the settings page.

Here are the [official guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/app-settings/guidelines-for-app-settings) for app settings. In general, I would take inspiration in the Windows 10 Settings app and try to make the interface match its design at least partially, so that it is familiar to the user.

Comment: Marked as solved - this makes sense as a path moving forward. Thank you.